# HDFS over S3 / Google storage bucket translation layer - how?

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs, bucket, gcsfuse

I'd love to expose a Google storage bucket over HDFS to a service.
Service in question is a cluster (SOLR) that can speak only to HDFS, given I have no hadoop (nor need for it), ideally I'd like to have a docker container that would user a Google storage bucket as a backend and expose it's contents via HDFS.
If possible I'd like to avoid mounts (like fuse gcsfs), has anyone done such thing?

I think I could just do mount gcsfs and setup a single node cluster with HDFS, but is there a simpler / more robust way?

Any hints / directions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cloud Storage Connector for Hadoop](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage) is the tool you might need.

It is not a Docker image but rather an install. Further instructions can be found in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/tree/master/gcs) under README.md and INSTALL.md

If it is accessed from AWS S3 you'll need a Service Account with access to Cloud Storage and set the env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to /path/to/keyfile.

---

To use SOLR with GCS, you need indeed a hadoop cluster and you can do that in GCP by creating a dataproc cluster then use the connector mentioned to connect your SOLR solution with GCS. for more info check this [SOLR](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/solr)

Comment: I am not sure how would this help... With this I would need a hadoop (which I don't have) as well as all interaction form solr with gcs:// instead of hdfs:// which solr doesn't do.

Also, in the mean time we managed to actualy create a solr plugin which adds a GCS repository for backup / restore directly in solr. It's a simple implementation which, instead of talking directly to gcs copies backup to and from gcs to local FS and restores from there.

Comment: to use SOLR with GCS, you need indeed a hadoop cluster and you can do that in GCP by creating a dataproc cluster then use the connector mentioned by @Juancki to connect your SOLR solution with GCS. for more infor check this 
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/solr